# Emacs 24 client not loading color theme properly

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24, archlinux

I want to use the color theme solarized-light. It works just fine if I do `(load-theme 'solarized-light t)`, however I am having issues with having it load automatically.

If I simply add `(load-theme 'solarized-light t)` to my .emacs, the color theme won't load properly. Some of the colors are applied but others aren't, I assume this is because it's not running in a GUI so it assumes the terminal can't support the colors or something.

Logically, I tried putting the call to load the theme in the `after-make-frame-functions` variable. I thought that if it only tries to load the theme after I'm already in a GUI, then it should work right?

It doesn't. When I create the first frame the same thing happens with the terminal and the colors aren't loaded properly. However, if I make another frame while I already have one open then it works properly.

Is there any way to apply the theme properly when I make the first frame, or even before that if possible?

I'm on Arch Linux running Emacs 24.3.1 as a **daemon**. In case this behavior is tied to the window manager, I've tried it in both StumpWM and Openbox and it doesn't work in either.

**Edit**:

As a temporary workaround I have made a command in my .stumpwmrc that runs the shell command `emacsclient --eval "(load-theme 'solarized-light t)"` after making the frame. This works but it doesn't answer my original question (nor is it likely to help people with other window managers).

Comment: Instead of `after-make-frame-functions`, try adding it to `before-make-frame-hook`.  Not sure if this gambit will work, hence it's not yet a formal answer.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
(package-initialize)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
```

to the top of your .emacs file. then set the them from M-x customize-groups: themes, select theme in the menu and save to your .emacs file, also disable foreground and background from default faces group. restart emacs or M-x eval-buffers to check.